# During keyboard display state screen is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-xml, autoscroll

> I stuck from one day I tried multiple ways but not screen not auto
>   resizable I am using parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
>   theme but did not worked. I tried following process in Manifest File I
>   added following

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

> I added FrameLayout and ScrollView too as a root layout and child
>   layout but did not work.
>
> My code in xml file is

```
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forgot_screen_send_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_color_bg_rec"
            android:text="Send"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try making the root RelativeLayout into a ScrollView then set fitsSystemWindows="true" and remove one of the LinearLayouts. You don't need both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the manifest of your app:  In the `<activity tag>` ***`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`***

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        </activity>
```